# Interact with Android Setup Wizard

Tags: android, wizard

I am trying to develop a setup wizard for Android, as I would like to add some functionality to the one existing from Google. Is it possible to somehow interact with the Android wizard? Because when I have searched for information I've seen that not using Google's Wizard might cause some trouble, regarding gmail account activation and so on.

If not, could an activity be called immediately before or after Google's wizard? Would it be enough to just listen to the BOOT_COMPLETED event?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If not, I would be interested in knowing hot to add a google account to the device, skipping the Google wizard

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you will use this unless you are making a rom and can add your app to system but basically you make your setupwizard add-on a Home activity with action MAIN, and categories HOME,DEFAULT. You should also set the priority higher than 1. If any of this is unclear you can look at the Launcher source/manifest that is publicly available.

When your activity is done it should deactivate itself with the PackageManager ([setComponentEnabledSetting](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#setComponentEnabledSetting%28android.content.ComponentName,%20int,%20int%29)) and that should be it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional activities that start the first time the phone is boot up. You just have to mimic the same behavior as Google's `SetupWizardActivity`.

Here's the relevant portion in the `AndroidManifest.xml` for reference:

```
<activity android:theme="@style/InvisibleNoTitle" android:label="@string/setup_wizard_title" android:name="SetupWizardActivity" android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:immersive="true">
    <intent-filter android:priority="5">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEVICE_INITIALIZATION_WIZARD" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This will allow you to run your application before/after `SetupWizardActivity`, depending on your priority. I believe higher numbers for `android:prioirity` run first, but don't quote me on that.

You can find out the AndroidManifest `xml` for various Android-related apks using [apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/). You can even inspect some of apks you picked up from the Play Store or whatever other sources.